# Regex remove everything except the match

Tags: html, regex, autohotkey

I have a .ahk that give me something like below. I would like to only keep what is inside the HTML tag containing a `style`.

In the example below, I would like to only keep `<b style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34)>;"><span>A text </span></b>` and to remove everythin before and after.

This regex is matching what I want: `(<[b div span p] style=".*">.*<\/.*[div span p b]>)` but I am not able to only keep this match and to remove eveything else.

I have tried the substitution with $2 and \2 but it didn't work

**match:**

```
([.\r\n]*)(<[b div span p] style=".*">.*<\/.*[div span p b]>)([.\r\n]*)
```

The first group should match everything from the beginning to and including  and the third group should match everything from and including  to the end. 
Then I can only keep the second group.

**replace:**

```
\2
```

Here is my try: https://regex101.com/r/Bkq0JE/2

```
---------------------------
ahk html clipboard.ahk
---------------------------
Version:0.9

StartHTML:0000000159

EndHTML:0000002912

StartFragment:0000000195

EndFragment:0000002876

SourceURL:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genghis_Khan

<html>

<body>

<!--StartFragment--><b style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34)>;"><span>A text </span></b><!--EndFragment-->

</body>

</html>
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

Find: `.*<!--StartFragment-->(.*)<!--EndFragment-->.*`
 Replace: `$1`
 Modifiers: `gs`

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ZcAJtD/1).

Note that the `s` modifier makes the `.` also match newline characters. If you happen to use notepad++, then that option can be set with a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using notepad++? if so just do this hit `Ctrl + H` then do the following:

- Find what: `.*(<b\s[^>]*>.*<\/b>).*`
- Replace with: `$1`
- Search Mode: `Regular Expressions`
- Check off "Matches newlines"
- Click on "Replace" and done